# I want to click download button in Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the download button but it does not work.

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[contains(text(),'Download')]]""").click()
```

Error message is

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text(),'Download')]]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

and tried this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="Download"]""").click()
```

Error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Download"]"}
```

What`s the problem?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

search = "Acid Value"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/classification/#hid=72")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Chemical and Physical Properties')]").click() # click Chemical and Physical Properties button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Experimental Properties')]").click() # click Experimental Properties button 
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(text(),'{search}')]/parent::li/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'ui-button-text')][2]").click()
#click the Desired properties

driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[contains(text(),'Download')]]""").click() # error occur here ! 

    
    
driver.implicitly_wait(100) 

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[contains(text(),'SDF')]]""").click() #click the sdf download button
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
```

Comment: Hi, if you can perhaps show us a bit of the dom and the html that creates and surround this button it may be a bit easier to try and help you. Thank you.

Comment: do you get error mesage ? your xpath seems incorrect - you need triple `""" """` instead of single `" "`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first get all `//button` and display text in every button - maybe there is no button with `Download`. Or maybe it has different text, with some extra chars. Or maybe it is in some tag inside button.

Comment: you have typo - you have too much `]` in xpath `"""//button[contains(text(),'Download')]]"""` - you have to remove last `]`

Comment: Furas is correct you have too many ] and also remove the duplicate driver.implicitly_wait(10) you only need to set it once. The more ideal way would be webdriver waits. Also after clicking download instead of a random wait which I am assuming is for the downloading there are a variety of methods to check if your file has been downloaded.

Comment: It's also a div not a button.

Comment: text `Download` is not directly in button but in `div`. But there is `id="Download"` directly in button - maybe it will work.`

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Download')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='Download']").click()
```

Simple fix to click the download. You had a typo and the wrong html element. It's a div and not button. It was also in another window so you should driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) to that window.

I would also remove the implicit_wait() they only need to be set once. You can use explicit wait which tend to more stable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/classification/#hid=72")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(), 'Chemical and Physical Properties')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(), 'Experimental Properties')]"))).click()
# click Chemical and Physical Properties button
# click Experimental Properties button 
 
search = "Acid Value"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f"//span[contains(text(),'{search}')]/parent::li/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'ui-button-text')][2]"))).click()
#click the Desired properties
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#Download"))).click()
```

Comment: thanks your answer but "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Download')]").click()" code occur same error like "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'Download')]"}"

Comment: It seems that there was a  window switch as well.

Comment: I also found that there is problem with switched window/tab :) I think you should mention it in answer because it can be the main problem.